# Mapping Foreign Key twice with different names in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a MasterConfig table, where I want to store my values in CodeValue format. i.e

```
ID   CODE            VALUE
1.   BusinessType    IT
2.   BusinessType    Marketing
3.   ContractType    General
4.   ContractType    Custom
```

So, to get records based on CODE field. eg. getCodeValue/ContractType

Now, I have a Contract table where I have to map these fields as Foreign Keys. My contract model looks like:

```
public class Contract
{
   [Key]
   public int ID{get; set;}
   public string Name{get; set;}

   [ForeignKey("CodeValue")]
   public int BusinessTypeID{get; set;}

   [ForeignKey("CodeValue")]
   public int ContractTypeID{get; set;}

   public virtual CodeValue CodeValue {get; set;}
}
```

While creating Controller with view, I get error that "Unable to retrieve metadata for Contract Model. Not able to map the fields".

Please suggest me a solution for this Master Config relation in Entity Framework (ASP.NET MVC) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It needs to map against a navigation property in the `Contract` class, something like this:

```
public class Contract
{
   [Key]
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }

   [ForeignKey("BusinessType")]
   public int BusinessTypeID { get; set; }

   [ForeignKey("ContractType")]
   public int ContractTypeID { get; set; }

   public virtual CodeValue BusinessType { get; set; }
   public virtual CodeValue ContractType { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: So, created Individual Derived Classes on CodeValue and used those classes to link Foreign Keys.